# jQuery option select field value same in another option select field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone help me with this:

I have 2 fields with multiple select options, both fields have the same options to select.

Can someone help me with a jquery code which automatically select the same value on the second field?

Lets say in first field I select option "USA" I want jquery to automatically select the same option "USA" on the second field

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Note that it is a very rare the requirements of your question.. but yes it is possible.

You can attach a `change` event to your first element named `select1`, and then in the function handler set the field name `select2` value like this:

```js
$('select[name=select1]').on('change', function() {
  $('select[name=select2]').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select multiple name="select1">
  <option value="val1">Val 1</option>
  <option value="val2">Val 2</option>
  <option value="val3">Val 3</option>
  <option value="val4">Val 4</option>
  <option value="val5">Val 5</option>
</select>

<select multiple name="select2">
  <option value="val1">Val 1</option>
  <option value="val2">Val 2</option>
  <option value="val3">Val 3</option>
  <option value="val4">Val 4</option>
  <option value="val5">Val 5</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Here is what I have

Comment: Hey @Yosvel Quintero, I just checked the differences and seems in my case in first field, the value is not matching, first uses numbers, while the other uses names, any idea how to match them ?